# AngularJS directive: '&' in isolated scope isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass on a method from the controller into my directive. This is how I'm doing it:

In the controller:

```
$scope.getEmployees = function()
{
    return {2: 'Jane', 3: 'Bob', 4: 'Smith'};
}

$scope.getSelected = function()
{
    return 3;
}
```

In the view/HTML:

```
<mydirective data-placeHolder="Choose an employee.." 
       data-getOpts="getEmployees()" data-getSelected="getSelected()" />
```

In the directive:

```
var dir = 
{
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl : 'views/mydirective.html',
   scope: {
       placeholder: '@',
       getSelected: '&',
       getOpts: '&'
   },   
   controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 
       function($scope, $element, $attrs)
       {
           console.log( $scope.getOpts() );
       }],

};

MyApp.directive('mydirective', function()
 {
     return dir;
 });
```

However, the following line in the directive's controller:

```
   console.log( $scope.getOpts() );
```

Produces undefined rather than returning the object or the function set in the controller's `getEmployees()` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relating to naming convention. You need to convert the camel case to dash separated words like this

```
data-get-opts="getEmployees()"
```